# EditText getting shifted to bottom of layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using `appbarlayout` in my app and when I include that layout in my main layout and place `edittext` below that layout my `edittext` is getting shifted to bottom. What I'm trying to do is setting `edittext` below `toolbar` but it is getting shifted at bottom of layout and also the floating action button is showing bit higher than it is showing in editor.

My `toolbaractiivty`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"></android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here I'm including it in `main_activity`

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_activity"
        android:id="@+id/toolbaractivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbaractivity"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wrap_content` for `NestedScrollView`'s `layout_height`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"></android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks sir it works and sir with collapse of toolbar my edittext doesnt change its position